# Greek/Latin lexical or compositorial correspondences

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, ancient-greek, dictionary

I'm always intrigued by lexical correspondences and kinships and the underlying etymology (where it is not completely obvious, of course), such as between English *town* and German *Zaun*, English *war* and French *guerre*, or German *Wespe* and French *guêpe*.

The same word travels differnt ways and takes different turns, often changing meaning quite drastically.

Here's the kind of correspondence I'm looking for between ancient Greek (sorry for using modern Greek here) and Latin:

- μορφή forma
- νόμος norma (*not* lex *in this case*)
- μεταμόρφωση transformatio
- σύνθεση compositio
- συναγωγή congregatio

The first two are the same word with the same or a similar meaning. The third and fourth are close analogues in word formation. And the last one is a close semantic correspondence (driving the herd together so they can hear the gospel) if not also an analogue in word formation.

So what I'm looking for is more of the same, in the form of a thesaurus or catalogue. Not a full-fledged dictionary, just a list of these etymological eye-openers, especially for words important in modern language use. I would imagine that such lists should exist for theology or philosophy.

I've done some googling but to no avail. Do you know of any such catalogues?

Inclusion of additional word-forming languages such as German or Russian welcome, too, but my interest here is in Greek and Latin.

---

Update: I found a book that might offer what I'm looking for, building bridges from Latin to Greek. It's apparently more than a mere list:

*Le vocabulaire latin de la philosophie*
– par Jean-Michel Fontanier
– [Éditions ellipses](https://www.eyrolles.com/Loisirs/Livre/le-lexicon-9782753577619/)

> Dans ce Vocabulaire latin de la philosophie le dessein est triple : **établir des ponts avec la terminologie grecque**, faire apparaître les équivoques possibles, mais, avant tout, illustrer les divers sens de chaque mot, d'Absolutus à Voluptas. D'où l'abondance des citations ou, à défaut, des références …

Catalogue de l'auteur chez [Eyrolles](https://www.eyrolles.com/Accueil/Auteur/jean-michel-fontanier-51617/), entre autres le *Dictionnaire trilingue français, latin, grec*.

Comment: The first type is generally called a _cognate_, the second type is a _calque_.

Comment: The etymology of *norma* is in dispute, but it definitely cannot be the same word as νόμος.

Comment: You're asking for two quite different things here. Cognates between Greek and Latin are very numerous and hard to list exhaustively, and calques wouldn't belong in the same list.

Comment: @TKR – The distinction you're making is certainly valid but doesn't make much of a difference in terms of practical usefulness for a learner of Greek and/or Latin. Exhaustiveness is not a criterium as the most used or relevant words are also the most useful ones. I thought such lists would certainly exist but maybe the desire to see that kind of connection is not as wide-spread among learners and teachers as I thought. You can certainly build your own list over time, but if something is already in existence, why not take that as a starting point?